# How to use Ionic Twitter Connect Plugin to post a tweet

Tags: angular, twitter, ionic4

I am developing an app where I want to post a tweet, I have searched far and wide to find a solution on how to post a tweet in an ionic/angular app, but so far this seems to be my only hope.

In the git repo for the native twitter connect ionic plugin, there is a section that states

**OpenComposer**

Calls the tweet composer in order to send tweets with embedded images and other. Must be authenticated in order to open the composer.

```
TwitterConnect.openComposer('insert default text here, can be empty',
  function() {
    console.log('Success');
  },
  function() {
    console.log('Error');
  }
);
```

here is the link to the repo https://github.com/chroa/twitter-connect-plugin#opencomposer

However this does not seem to work when I try it, does anybody have any solutions on how to get this to work.

this is my implementation of it, I do have a sign up and login method for twitter

```
sendTweet(){
  this.twitter.openComposer('insert default text here, can be empty',
  function() {
    console.log('Success');
  },
  function() {
    console.log('Error');
  }
);
}
```

This is the error message that I get

```
Property 'openComposer' does not exist on type 'TwitterConnect'
```

i would just like to know how to post a tweet from within your app.

Comment: How you tried other possibilities, that repo you are referring is quite old. You could use the Twitter Api instead, there are angular libraries that works perfectly fine the only thing you need to do is to create your own form in the app.
Using this library for example  https://github.com/Aoinu/ng2-twitter

Comment: Please include the code for the declaration of `this.twitter`. Why are you using `this.twitter` instead of `TwitterConnect`?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the Twitter API. You check it’s docs out here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs